# How do I express that something is distributed over an interval?

Tags: notation, article-writing

I have a set of states between $t=0$ and $t\to\infty$. I'd like to write the following:

> The states are distributed over $t=\left(0,\infty\right)$, so the intervals in $t$ between them are indeterminate.

What would be an idiomatic way to write this? If *indeterminate* is the wrong word, what would be an accurate way to express that we can't access the time intervals because we can't take finite partitions of an infinite duration?

Comment: Note that my reasoning is actually incorrect because I've taken a subset of an infinite number of intermediate states and mistakenly used the finiteness of my subset, which I believe isn't related to how the states are distributed. I'm leaving the question as a notation thing.

Comment: Since the days of Kolmogorov (if not centuries earlier) the concept of something indeterminate being distributed over an interval is expressed as a random variable having a probability distribution.

Comment: Hi @KurtG., if you want to make this an answer I'll accept it. Thanks